# C/C++ programs hang in Windows 7 console

Tags: windows-7, c++, c

I've installed Windows 7 Home Premium. It's working fine, except one major problem.

When I run any C or C++ program in the console, using any software like Dev-C++, Code::Blocks or Visual Studio, it takes too long to respond. It also does not kill the process of that `.exe` file – even when I close the console window. It repeatedly shows the previous output, not the newly compiled output.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example or show a screenshot? What do you mean by "previous output"? Do you see anything in the Task Manager?

Comment: The previous output seems like user error.  It "taking to long" sounds like the code is at fault.

Comment: Make sure your program is not to blame here! @slhck: He probably means that the console isn't cleared for each run of program which can happen depending on IDE AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

From your start button take a look at Computer Management | Event Viewer | Windows Logs

Hope this might help a little.